# Not able to take screenshot on MacBook Pro Retina

Tags: macbook-pro, screen-capture

I am trying to take screenshot on MacBook Pro Retina using the shortcut commands shift+command+3 and shift+command+4 but nothing happens . I also have checked System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts and checked all the boxes but still doesn't works. Please help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. The pictures should be saved to the Desktop and named "Screen Shot <date>". If you sort your Desktop items by name, aren't there any with such a name?

Comment: No after shift+command+4 mouse pointer does not changes to plus sign

Comment: What is your macOS version? Do the Shift and Command keys work with other key combinations, like Command-C to copy? Have you tried changing the key combination in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Screenshots? As a workaround, you can use the app Screenshot, located in `/Applications/Utilities/Screenshot`. See https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/take-screenshots-or-screen-recordings-mh26782/mac for more information.